# shared resources between scripts

Tags: terraform

Sorry for the noob question... I'm  trying to figure out a way to have shared resources between my tf scripts, but I can't find anything, so probably I'm looking for the wrong keywords...

Let's say I have 3 scripts:

```
base/base.tf
one/one.tf
two/two.tf
```

base creates an aws vpc and a network load balancer
one and two are two ecs fargate services. they create the task definition and add the mappind to the network load balancer.

My goal is to have something to keep track of the mapped port in the load balancer and read it and update from one and two.

Something like
base sets last_port to 14000
one reads last_port, increases by 1 and updates the value
two reads last_port, increases by 1 and updates the value

Is it possible at all ?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `last_port`?

Comment: Attaching your `.tf` files would be helpful too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution to this problem in Terraform is [Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html), which are special resources that retrieve data from elsewhere rather than creating and managing objects themselves.

In order to use data sources, the data you wish to share must be published somewhere. For sharing *between* Terraform configurations, you need a data storage location that can be both written to and read from by Terraform.

Since you mentioned ECS Fargate I will assume you're using AWS, in which case a reasonable choice is to store your data in AWS SSM Parameter Store and then have other configurations read it out.

The configuration that *creates* the data would use [the `aws_ssm_parameter` resource type](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ssm_parameter.html) to create a new parameter:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  name  = "port_number"
  type  = "String"
  value = aws_lb_listener.example.port
}
```

The configurations that will make use of this data can then read it using [the corresponding data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ssm_parameter.html):

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  name = "port_number"
}
```

However, your question talks about the possibility of one configuration reading the value, incrementing it, and writing the new value back into the same place. That is not possible with Terraform because Terraform is a declarative system that works with descriptions of a *static desired state*. Only one configuration can be managing each object, though many configurations can *read* an an object.

Instead of dynamically allocating port numbers then, Terraform will require one of two solutions:

- Use some other system to manage the port allocations persistently such that once a port number is allocated for a particular caller it will always get the same port number. I don't know of any existing system that is built for this, so this may not be a tenable option in this case, but if such a system did exist then we'd model it in Terraform with a resource type representing a particular port allocation, which Terraform can eventually destroy along with all of the other infrastructure when the port is no longer needed.
- Decide on a systematic way to assign consistent port numbers to each system such that each configuration can just *know* (either by hard-coding or by some deterministic calculation) which port number it should use.